# Python (3.3) Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program using python which can help us tell the time, date and year, however I am facing a few problems.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_day = now.day
print current_day
current_month = now.month
print current_month
current_year = now.year
print current_year
input(press enter to exit)
```

Each time I run it, it says invalid syntax, apparently its something to do with the third line.I'm not sure what to do! Can anyone help me?

Comment: If that's your actual code then you need quotation marks around the input and print is a function... can you also add spaces around the `=` sign please?

Comment: i took away the input because it says it is causing an error, and it keeps on closing as soon as it opens. Can you show what the script should look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Python 3 doesn't use the same `print` syntax as Python 2. `print` in Python 3 is a function, so you need `print(current_day)`

Comment: do i still have to do line 2?

Comment: By line 2, do you mean `now=datetime.now()`? Why wouldn't you need that?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.x, you have to do `print(current_day)`.  `print` is no longer a keyword like in 2.x but a built-in.

This is how your script should be in Python 3.x:

```
from datetime import datetime
now=datetime.now()
current_day=now.day
print(current_day)
current_month=now.month
print(current_month)
current_year=now.year
print(current_year)
# You have to make "press enter to exit" a string.
# Otherwise, the script will blow up because "press" isn't defined.
input("press enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 has not print operator! It has print function: You need to print(smthn).
Also `input("press enter to exit")`

Comment: missed quotes in your question

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you need to use the print function, not the the print statement in Python3.  You can also further simplify your code:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print("{0.day}-{0.month}-{0.year}".format(now))
input('Press any key to exit')
```

You can find out more about the [print function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) and the [format syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

At first that's python 2.7 code.
And this is complete fix of your code in python3

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_day = now.day
print(current_day)
current_month = now.month
print(current_month)
current_year = now.year
print(current_year)

input("Press Enter to exit")
```

And for python 2.7 this is a quick fix..

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_day = now.day
print current_day
current_month = now.month
print current_month
current_year = now.year
print current_year
try:
    input("press enter to exit")
except SyntaxError:
    pass
```